# PHP library for making RSS feeds valid?

Tags: php, rss, feed

Often PHP is unable to import RSS feeds because they either contain invalid characters, are not terminated properly somewhere or are not properly encoded. I wonder if there's any PHP library, that can go over such invalid feeds and try to fix them (make them valid)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using PHP tidy module,
it works good in cleaning up invalid HTML,XML,XHTML markup.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.tidy.php